# Map object's existence to a Boolean property with NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

**Background**: I am connecting to a ***legacy*** Database that has two entities:

```
Order (Id, Date, ...)    

ForwardOrder(OrderId)
```

... as you can see ForwardOrder could be just a property of an Order

**Requirements**: Try to reflect ForwardOrder as a Boolean property of Order class in .NET. Connect to the database with NHibernate.

**The problem**: I tried implementing IUserType but no luck - column doesn't exist error.

The mapping is `Map(x=>x.IsForwardOrder).CustomType<ForwardOrderType>();`

Adding a Formula does make it load properly, but the IUserType setter is never used.

**Question**: Can it be done? Can an object's existence in a separate table be a flag on my Entity? I know that I can just map a related object but I would rather to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is set up the `ForwardOrder` as a protected property on the code level and treat it like a lazy component.  Then you can actually leave `IsForwardOrder` out of your NHibernate mapping completely and just do something like:

```
  public bool IsForwardOrder { get { return ReferenceEquals(this.ForwardOrder,null); } }
```

You **could** use polymorphism as well, but it seems like overkill for a boolean.  This approach would entail creating a subclass that has the ForwardOrder property and defining a [table-per-subclass join](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#inheritance-tablepersubclass) to the `ForwardOrder` table.  You would still need to define a boolean property like

```
  public virtual bool IsForwardOrder { get { return false; } }
```

on the base class

```
  public override bool IsForwardOrder { get { return true; } }
```

on the joined subclass.

Alternatively, with this approach, you could use an extension method such as

```
 public static bool IsForwardOrder(this Order order) { return order is ForwardOrder; }
```

(assuming the base class is `Order` and the subclass is `ForwardOrder`)

Comment: Thank You for the reply! I am interested if it's possible to avoid mapping ForwardOrder entity at all?

Comment: @Turowicz,  Yes, of course.  You can just not configure it.  The join shouldn't be automatically detected if you don't define it.

Comment: @Turowicz, But then you wouldn't know if it was a ForwardOrder or not.  Is there any reason you can't sanitize this issue at the db level?  (An example of a good reason would be that legacy code that is out of your control is responsible for marking the Order as "forward" with a DB insert)

Comment: I'd pretty much rather not to change anything in the legacy database. I will map the FO entity and do as you said. Thanks!